# Pymongo text index formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to index a `text field` using **pymongo**

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo_client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = mongo_client["db_name"]
```

The objects look like this:

```sh
{'_id': ObjectId('5cf7d2d58a662ef15600033f'),
 'id': '13055',
 'type': 'municipality',
 'name': 'Marseille',
 'postcode': '13000',
}
```

I am trying to index the field `name` as a `string` to be able to perform text search on it, unfortunately, I was unsuccessful after multiple attempts:

```py
db.collection.create_index([{"$name": "text"}])
```

yields the error:

```sh
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Similarly, the command

```py
db.collection.create_index([{"name": "text"}])
```

yields the same error:

```sh
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I am sure this is a simple formatting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, the format needed to be:

```py
db.collection.create_index([("name": "text")])
```